# TCP vs UDP traffic creation

Tags: video, tcp, udp, video-streaming, httpserver

I have a network with two hosts, and I am performing two experiments :

**1.** In the first case, I am streaming a video from the one host to the other using the command :

```
vlc-wrapper [PATH_TO_VIDEO] --sout '#rtp{dst=[RECEIVER_IP],port=1234}'
```

and in Wireshark I can see that the receiver host receives **UDP** packets.

**2.** In the second case, I have made the sender host an HTTP server, and the receiver host requests the video like this :

```
wget -O [RECEIVER_IP/PATH_TO_VIDEO]
```

and in Wireshark I can see that the receiver host receives **TCP** packets.

I understand that the second case is like YouTube, so it's expected to see TCP packets. But why am I seeing UDP packets in the second case?

I mean, I am sending the same video. What is the factor which differentiates the traffic type in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTP is by definition UDP: "RTP typically runs over User Datagram Protocol (UDP)."
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)

wget uses HTTP which is by definition TCP.

In both cases - the specification of the protocol determines the transport.

Comment: thanks for your answer. May I ask a clarification: If I wanted to create TCP traffic (instead of UDP) with the same video using the first command, is there a way I could do it?

Comment: Some RTP server (for example Live555 Media Server) would do TCP if the client requests TCP transmissions. You could try blocking UDP traffic to your server (for example with a firewall) and see if your client switches to TCP. If you have client and server under control than you may able to force both sides to only do TCP.